# Does Akka run multiple instances of the same event concurrently?

Tags: heroku, playframework, akka, playframework-2.1

I'm using Akka in Play Framework instead of a Job, to schedule code to run every X seconds. My code is running on Heroku free tier, which I believe is sometimes suspended for a while and then resumed by the Heroku system.

Is it possible that when the Heroku dyno wakes up, it notices it has a few events "it owes" and so runs them concurrently? My code is not thread safe, and assumes that only one event will be run at any given time.

This is the actor setup that is run on Play start:

```
object Global extends GlobalSettings {

  override def onStart(app: Application) {
    val monitorActor = Akka.system.actorOf(Props[MonitorLoadJob], name = "monitorLoad")
    Akka.system.scheduler.schedule(0 seconds, 10 seconds, monitorActor, Tick)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actors process one message at a time, so if you use the scheduler to send a Tick message in every 10 seconds to monitorActor, the processing of that Tick message in monitorActor has to be sequential -- independent of whether messages come in late in a batch, or not.

If you observe concurrent behavior, then something else is going wrong.